# Register Route not working in JWT Implementation ExpressJS

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Working on an authentication scheme for an app, and I'm implementing JWT from scratch. I've confirmed I can login as a user that is already registered in the DB (mongo) and I'm trying to code up a registration route.

here is my `/register` route:

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    log.info('Checking password')
    if (req.body.password !== req.body.password2) {
        res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: "Passwords do not match" });
    } else {
        log.info('password verification successful');
    }
    //Parse the user from the body.
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            let u = new User({
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                username: req.body.userName,
                password: hash,
                registeredApps: []
            });
            log.info(u.toString());
            u.save((err) => {
                if (err) {
                    log.error('error saving user to database.');
                    log.error(err);
                    res.status(400).send(err);
                } else {
                    log.info('user successfully saved.');
                    res.status(200).send({ success: true });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I can confirm that my user object does get to the route, but it appears that nothing in the `u.save()` method. Nothing happens, and the user is not being saved to the database.

Comment: if using [`Model.save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) method then try a callback with two parameters i.e. `u.save((err, user) => { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty solution is that I forgot to call `Mongoose.connect` in the code.

Apologies for the poor/tricky question.